# Updating php command on web hosting

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface, web-hosting

I've tried to install a php application on a server, using `php composer.phar install`.

At first all seamed well, except it said the php version was to low. A quick `php -v` told us, that the php version running the cli php command was `4.4.9`. After a little trial and error, I've managed to find another command `php7 -v` which is php version `7.0.6`. So I've tried `php7 composer.phar install` which looked good at first, but it seams that it called a few other php scripts (for building the php autoloader, that Symfony uses) with the original php function (which is 4.4.9).

Is there a way to overwrite the php function to always use php7 while on command-line? If this helps anyhow, as far as I can tell, `php7` is a shortcut for `/usr/local/bin/php7.0.6-cli`

Note: I can connect to the server using SSH, but as it's a normal webhosting, I don't have root/sudo access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default PHP binary using your PATH.

First, create a `~/bin` directory:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

In `~/.bashrc`, add the following line:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This adds your `~/.bin` directory to your environment's PATH variable. You can test this by either starting a new shell, or running the following:

```
echo $PATH;source ~/.bashrc;echo $PATH
```

Then, you can create a symlink in your `~/bin` directory:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php7.0.6-cli ~/bin/php
```

The output of `which php` should then return:

```
/home/<user>/bin/php
```